# Interpolation between Sobolev spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces, interpolation, interpolation-spaces

In the classical book $Interpolation$ $Spaces$ by Joran Bergh and Jorgen Lofstrom, the Sobolev norm is defined by
$$\|f\|_{H_p^s}=\|D^sf\|_{L^p}$$
where $D^sf$ is defined by the Fourier transform
$$(D^sf)^\wedge(\xi)=(1+|\xi|^2)^{s/2}\hat f(\xi).$$

I find the interpolation spaces between Sobolev spaces $H_p^s(\mathbb{R}^n)$ in Theorem 6.4.5(7) (page 152-153):

$$(H_{p_0}^{s_0},H_{p_1}^{s_1})_{[\theta]}=H_{p}^s,\ \ s_0\ne s_1,\ 1<p_0,p_1<\infty,$$
where $0<\theta<1$, $s=(1-\theta)s_0+\theta s_1$, $\frac1p=\frac{1-\theta}{p_0}+\frac\theta{p_1}$.

My question is: When $s_0\ne s_1$, what is the interpolation space between $H^{s_0}_{1}$ and $H^{s_1}_{\infty}$?

Note that when $s_0=s_1=s$, Theorem 6.4.5(5) tells us that the interpolation space between $H^s_1$ and $H^s_\infty$ is still $H_p^s$ with $p=\frac1\theta$.